# Record voice command and later use it as an action trigger

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Is there a framework I can use to record users voice command and than later recognize that same voice command to trigger some action with very little delay time.

For example I would record user saying "bishop" and "A8" and later user that same voice command to move the chess pieces around.

Comment: There is no need to record, you can successfully play chess with generic speech recognition engine. Recently one guy have just created the cool app like that with cmusphinx, you can find more information here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2016/03/jabberchess-a-mobile-chess-app-speech-recognizer-for-visual-and-motion-impaired-users/

Comment: generic speech recognition is for english I presume. For example A8 in english is very different from italian, swedish or french version of it. That's why I am after recording in the first place.

Comment: Models for French and Swedish are available too, you can create Italian pretty easily. It is much better for user to start without the need to record 20 commands.

Comment: woah than great! :D which generic speech recognition engine do you recommend?